# XAMPP Server Installation issues

Tags: apache, installation, xampp

I have attached a screenshot!
I am unable to figure out why this error is coming!

I uninstalled previous version and I am trying to install newer version but this error is coming:

[image: http://ge.tt/6Ny7SqW/v/0]

Please tell me how to solve this!

Answer (score 0):

Deactivate UAC from control panel and then try to intall XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the User Account Control.
http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-disable-and-turn-off-uac-in-windows-7/
Restart and install xampp.